# How to wrap code that uses transcations in a transaction and then rollback?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js, strapi

I'm setting up my integration testing rig. I'm using the `beforeEach` and `afterEach` hooks to wrap every single test in a transaction that rollsback so that the tests don't affect each other. A simplified example might be this:

```js
const { repository } = require("library")

describe("Suite", function () {
  beforeEach(async function () {
    await knex.raw("BEGIN");
  });

  afterEach(async function () {
    await knex.raw("ROLLBACK");
  });

  it("A test", async function () {
    const user = await repository.createUser()
    user.id.should.equal(1)
  });
});
```

This worked fine because I configured knex to use a single DB connection for tests. Hence calling `knex.raw("BEGIN");` created a *global* transaction.

Now however, the library's repository which I can't control started using transactions internally. I.e. `createUser()` begins and then *commits* the created user. This broke my tests as now my `afterEach` hook doesn't rollback the changes because they were already committed.

Is there a way in Postgres to rollback a transaction that have (already committed) nested transactions?

Or maybe a way to use knex to prevent the repository from starting transactions in the first place? It uses `knex.transaction()` to create them.

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, no, you can't rollback after commit. PostgreSQL supports nested transactions through [savepoints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-savepoint.html). Knex [documentation](https://knexjs.org/guide/transactions.html#:~:text=does%20not%20support-,savepoints,-in%20transactions.) randomly mentions that Redshift does not support savepoints but it doesn't say if and how those are exposed when working with PostgreSQL. Ideally, I would expect knex to detect when a nested transaction is created and switch from `commit`/`rollback` to `savepoint s1`/`release s1`/`rollback to s1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As may be guessed from the tags the library in question is [Strapi](https://strapi.io/) and I'm trying to write tests for the custom endpoints I implemented with it.

As noted by @zagarek, Postgres itself can't rollback already committed transactions. Knex does support nested transactions (using save-points) but you must explicitly refer to the parent transaction when creating a new one for it to get nested.

Many tried to achieve this setup. See the threads under e.g. [here](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/263) or [here](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/2076). It always boils down to somehow passing the test-wrapping transcation all the way down to your ORM/repository/code under test and instructing it to scope all queries under that transaction.

Unfortunately, Strapi doesn't provide any way to be given a transaction nor to create a global one. Now, cover your eyes and I'll tell you how I hacked around this.

I leverage one nice aspect of Knex: its Transaction object behaves (mostly) the same as a Knex instance. I mercilessly replace Strapi's reference of Knex instance with a Knex transaction and then rollback it in `afterEach` hook. To not make this too easy, Strapi extends its knex instance with a `getSchemaName` function. I therefore extend the transaction in disguise too and proxy to the original.

This does it: (Note that I'm using [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) where `this` can be used to pass state between hooks and/or tests.)

```js
const Strapi = require("@strapi/strapi");

before(async function () {
  // "Load" Strapi to set the global `strapi` variable.
  await Strapi().load();
  // "Listen" to register API routes.
  await strapi.listen();
  // Put aside Strapi's knex instance for later use in beforeEach and afterEach hooks.
  this.knex = strapi.db.connection;
});

after(async function () {
  // Put back the original knex instance so that Strapi can destroy it properly.
  strapi.db.connection = this.knex;
  await strapi.destroy();
});

beforeEach(async function () {
  // Replace Strapi's Knex instance with a transaction.
  strapi.db.connection = Object.assign(await this.knex.transaction(), {
    getSchemaName: this.knex.getSchemaName.bind(this.knex),
  });
});

afterEach(async function () {
  strapi.db.connection.rollback();
});

it("Health-check is available.", async function () {
  // Any changes made within here will get rolled back once the test finishes.
  await request(strapi.server.httpServer).get("/_health").expect(204);
});
```

Lastly, it's worth noting that some Knex maintainers [persistently](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/263#issuecomment-401143825) [discourage](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/2076#issuecomment-374913051) using transcations to isolate tests so consider if chasing this hacky setup is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the looks of an [example debug log](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/3389#issuecomment-519811122), knex does in fact detect transaction nesting automatically and switches nested transactions from using irreversible `commit`/`rollback` to [manageable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-savepoint.html) `savepoint s1`/`release s1`/`rollback to s1` the way I was guessing in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74387244/how-to-wrap-code-that-uses-transcations-in-a-transaction-and-then-rollback#comment131502339_74387244).

In this case, it should be enough for you to wrap your calls in a transaction, so that you "own" the top-level one. Knex should detect this and force the underlying transactions to use savepoints instead of commits, all of which you can then undo, rolling back the top-level transaction. If I read [the doc](https://knexjs.org/guide/transactions.html) right:

```javascript
const { repository } = require("library")
 
describe("Suite", function () {
  it("A test", async function () {
    try {
        await knex.transaction(async trx => {
          const user = await repository.createUser();
          user.id.should.equal(1);
          trx.rollback();
        })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  });
});
```

That's assuming none of the calls below issues a `knex.raw("COMMIT")` or somehow calls `.commit()` on the outer, top-level transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Unfortunately, Knex cannot detect nested transaction if they're not created explicitly using the parent transaction. I.e. your example wouldn't be translated to safe-points but remain as a `BEGIN; BEGIN; COMMIT; COMMIT;` sequence.

I ended up using some ugly hacks to tuck a transaction under hands of the `repository`. Then, Knex indeed creates save-points and I'm able to roll them back. For anyone coming back to this I recommend reading the discussions under https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/263 and https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/2076.

Comment: @Jen I see. I overlooked the fact that the examples in the doc keep explicitly referring to the exact transaction instance that was created around them - nothing automagic about that. So what you did was somehow intercept everyone's calls to instantiate a transaction, regardless of context, taking over the "transaction factory"? Was it possible thanks to some specifics of your setup, or would you be able to describe the general idea? I'd say in this case a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) would be more than justified

Comment: Gimme a sec. I'll write down what I did. Nothing I'd be proud of but it still might be helpful to some. .)

Comment: Done. I'll award you the bounty for the effort. It'd be pity if it just expired. Thanks!